# How to implement default value fallback in ansible with dictionaries?

Tags: ansible

I want to improve the code below so it will always fallback to `omit` when it cannot find the value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
      ansible_connection: local
      foo:
         bar:
           12: 'xxx'
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "component_config={{ foo.bar[12] | default(omit) }}"
```

Current code works as expected only if `foo.bar` is a dictionary but fails if bar or even foo are not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK only via "nested" `default`:

```
{{ ((foo|default({})).bar|default({}))[12] | default(omit) }}
```